# Review Queue Desktop Notification Script

Tags: script, greasemonkey, notifier, tampermonkey, review

This Script will make it so that you are notified on the Desktop whenever new reviews are available, as long as you have a review tab open.

#### How to use

- Install [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome) or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox). These are userscript managers and allow the script to make use of `GM_*` functions
- Install the script: <kbd>[install](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier/raw/master/UserScript/ReviewQueueNotification.user.js)</kbd>
  or <kbd>[view source](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier/blob/master/UserScript/ReviewQueueNotification.user.js)</kbd>
- ***Any time you have a review queue window open***, the script will run and alert you anytime there are reviews to be performed.

## Updates

- Review Queue Notifier no longer counts reviews that you cannot currently review

#### Notes

- I will continue to make advancements with the code, so please keep an eye on this project.
- This Script is an altered version of [@Simon André Forsberg's](https://stackapps.com/users/31047/simon-andr%C3%A9-forsberg) script, [please check out his version with Moderator Notifications](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97268/desktop-notifications-for-flags-and-queue-items)
- [Donate to future development](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=7PTJ7V3ERTYWQ)
- [This is being developed into a Chrome Extension, if you would like to help check out the Repo](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier)

#### Known issues

Please post issues here or on the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/malachi26/ReviewQueueNotifier)

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment it's working perfectly!

Comment: @Edlothiad, if you have any suggestions, please let me know. I would like to get this going again, I have plans to make it work in Edge as well last time I looked at it it required rewriting the entire thing using translators though.

Comment: I am kind of curious to know how many people are actually using this as well?

Comment: I've been using it for around 6 months now. I like it. Although I saw you planned on being able to click on the notification and that would take you straight to the review. That would be practical. I only have a limited knowledge of how it functions. But it's been preforming admirably to date and would recommend it to anyone using the "review stalker" script

Comment: I don't know. Afaik I need the stalker to refresh constantly so yours knows when a new review has come up.

Comment: Currently, I think mine has to have the page open on one of your tabs, and refreshes itself every so often.  I was looking into having settings in the Chrome Extension....